# ImportError (missing dependencies ['numpy']) at the time of executing the .exe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pyinstaller

I made a little Python program in order to extract data (.csv files) from a several compressed gzip files using Pandas, gzip and shutil libraries. Once they are extracted the .csv files are joined in one big .csv unique file.

My program supports Python versions **2.7** and **3.7**.

When building an .exe to make easier the use of this little program and also compatible with computers that don't have Python installed, I'm making mistakes because it doesn't work.

This is the main folder in which I'm executing the .exe from PyInstaller:

[image: main folder]

Note: The "00000(0)" files are .gzip without extension, inside which there is just one .csv file, also without extension.

Do you have a way of solving this?

This is what I obtained from the terminal at the time of real execution:

[image: Terminal]

Terminal command to create the .exe:

`pyinstaller.exe --clean --onefile Convierte_Rar_En_Csv_Final.py --name Transforma2 --hidden-import numpy`

Versions:

- Python : 2.7.15
- pyinstaller: 3.4 (for installing this library I just downloaded the folder from [here](https://www.pyinstaller.org/downloads.html) then move it to `C:\YourPythonEnviroment\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-3.4` and finally made from the terminal once I'm inside the folder PyInstaller-3.4 `python setup.py install`.)
- pandas: 0.24.0
- numpy: 1.16.0
- pytz: 2018.9
- wxPython 4.0.4
- setuptools: 40.8.0
- python-dateutil: 2.8.0

Code of my program:

```
def DescomprimeYUne(path):
    import pandas as pd
    import gzip , shutil
    import numpy

    results = pd.DataFrame([])

    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        pathFile = path + filename
        if filename != __file__.split("/")[-1] and not os.path.isdir(pathFile):
            # # Descomprimo fichero
            with gzip.open(pathFile, 'rb') as f_in:
                with open(pathFile + '.csv', 'wb') as f_out:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)

            # Borro fichero original
            os.remove(pathFile)

            # Concateno a CSV final
            namedf = pd.read_csv(pathFile + ".csv", skiprows=0)
            results = results.append(namedf)

           # Borro fichero csv
           os.remove(pathFile + '.csv')

    results.to_csv(path + "final.csv")
if __name__ == "__main__":
DescomprimeYUne("./")
```

I followed also [this tutorial](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1886) but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

not to long ago i too distributed my python app as an executable. I also came across several import errors or missing file errors during run time however from my experience it seems the module cx_freeze is pretty good at getting it right.

Cx_freeze works on any os that python works on and support 2.7+ or 3+.
I would strongly recommend watching this tutorial it helped me out a lot.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HosXxXE24hA

Heres an example of the setup script:

```
import cx_Freeze 
from cx_Freeze import *
import sys 
import os


base = None

if sys.platform =='win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("DescomprimeYUne.py", base=base)]

# Stating what modules and files our app needs so they can be included in the build
cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "DescomprimeYUne", # Name of exe
    options = {"build_exe":{"packages":["numpy", "pandas", "gzip", "shutil"], # Include packages used here
                          "include_files":["filename"]}}, # optional you can include any files your script needs here
    version = "0.01",
    description="DescomprimeYUne",
    executables = executables
    )
```